# Assigning dynamic client Id of the Form to a Static Method Result

Tags: asp.net, user-controls, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I have more than one user controls with the javascript functions. I set control Id to the client function - to separate it from another. My javascript code looks like:

```
    function <%= this.ClientID %>UploadComplete(sender, args) {
....
}
```

And I want to register this method in the control declaration,

```
<ajaxToolkit:AsyncFileUpload runat="server" OnClientUploadComplete ="<%#uploaderror.ClientID%>UploadComplete"
        ID="AsyncFileUpload"/>
```

But in mark-Up I got

```
{"uploadComplete":<%#ClientID%>UploadComplete},"
```

Where uploaderror- 
I tried to use Attributes:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    AsyncFileUpload.Attributes.Add("OnClientUploadComplete", this.ClientID + "UploadComplete");
}
```

Mark-up was good. But event didn`t fire.

So I have two questions:
1) Why <%# - don`t works.
2) Why added by attributes events don`t fired in javascripts?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your first question, the reason it doesn't work is that  you cannot mix databinding code and text in a server control's property as you have done. It has to be one or the other. So what you could do instead is:

```
OnClientUploadComplete='<%# uploaderror.ClientID + "UploadComplete"%>'
```

Comment: <%# is for databinding -- are you not using this in the context of a control that you are databinding?

Comment: <%= will not work in server control properties, so that is not an option.

Comment: Sorry I don`t undestend your first question

Comment: In your variant event don`t fire. I think it depend of type - control required name of function - not a string.